# Is there a beginner Django book that doesn't teach how to create blogs?

Tags: django

I want to learn how to create simple Django web apps with database like an inventory system or simple list filtering site.  I'm getting a bit frustrated because all tutorials I see are all teaching me how to create blogs but I have no intention of creating blogs or social media sites.  I'm a beginner and I want to learn how to create super basic web apps and not full-blown social media sites.
I hope you can point me to a simple tutorial that tackles how to create simple apps that access database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That does not matter. The fact that they use a blog is not to teach you how to develop a blog-like system. The concepts of a blog can be used to develop all sorts of tools. Change `Blog` to `Product`, and all of a sudden the scope is different.

Comment: And I doubt any of those tutorials show to how to create "full-blown social media sites". Im not sure why you think a blog is a social media site.

Comment: If you read the tutorials carefully, you will see that it is more about how to construct a model (yes it is a  blog, but you could have used a `Product` instead). Next how to construct a `Form` (yes for a blog, but the process is very similar to constructing a `Form` to create/edit a `Product`), next how to get all blogs of an author (with one or two changes, you obtain all products of a supplier), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of tutorials that do not create blog apps :

- [Django official documentation tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) : They create simple apps for beginners level.
- [CodeMentor Django Web Application Tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/rogargon/simple-django-web-application-tutorial-du107rmn4) : Restaurants recommendation app
- [Medium.com tutorial](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/building-and-deploying-an-enterprise-django-web-app-in-16-hours-79e018f7b94c):Badges system
- [Simple is better than complex tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/07/a-minimal-django-application.html) : This the simplest and easiest of all
- [Scotch tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-your-first-python-and-django-application) : this is also a very simple one for first steps

The last two with no databases !

Enjoy and good luck.